# Fastest way to perform XOR using Javascript ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, bitwise-xor

I have a class representing bits and it uses `ArrayBuffers` to store the 
 binary data. I'm trying to figure out if there is a faster method to perform a `xor` between two `ArrayBuffers`.

***Note*** The length of the `ArrayBuffers` are usually less than 10 bytes. But since the `xor` operation is performed millions, if not billions of times, every millisecond saved matters.

```
// my current/simple method
// assume 'buf1', 'buf2' & 'result' are ArrayBuffers
for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
  result[i] = buf1[i] ^ buf2[i];
}
```

***Note*** Seeking solution executable both locally and on browser.

Comment: Parallel.js's`map`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I thought that but isn't the overhead of spawning worker threads/process each xor of less than a 10 bytes worth it?

Comment: Write a c / rust binding. I dont think that this can be made faster in js ( except asm.js or parallel threads)

Comment: @JonasW. Updated my question to specify "pure javascript solution." Thanks for your input.

Comment: If the datasets are that small, I think your current solution should be more than adequate. My suggestion is to measure the performance both with your solution and with Parallel and see for yourself which solution is better in your case.

Comment: Do you count WebAssembly as javascript? It runs in the browser too but is actually not js

Comment: @JonasW. Interesting... I don't know about WebAssembly, but please do tell. I'll edit my question again to specify browser compatibility

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca is right. BUT if you find that real use yields really big arrays (at least some thousands of bytes) could be interesting to make use of the graphics 2D acceleration (if available) using a canvas, so you are sending the hard "calculation work" to a -probably- parallellized GPU.

Comment: [You can find more about `WebAssembly` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Concepts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of 4 ways to calculate `XOR`:

- the native `^` operator
- `(n1+n2)%2`
- `n1+n2-2*n1*n2`
- use a preset array: `xor=[[0,1],[1,0]]`

I ran the following code, you can see the results for yourself:

```js
buf1=new Array(10000).fill(1).map((x)=>Math.floor(Math.random()*2));
buf2=new Array(10000).fill(1).map((x)=>Math.floor(Math.random()*2));

console.time('go');
for (let i=0;i<10000;i++) r=buf1[i]^buf2[i];
console.timeEnd('go');

console.time('go');
for (let i=0;i<10000;i++) r=(buf1[i]+buf2[i])%2;
console.timeEnd('go');

console.time('go');
for (let i=0;i<10000;i++) r=buf1[i]+buf2[i]-2*buf1[i]*buf2[i];
console.timeEnd('go');

xor=[[0,1],[1,0]];
console.time('go');
for (let i=0;i<10000;i++) r=xor[buf1[i]][buf2[i]];
console.timeEnd('go');
```

All the methods seem to give similar results.

Comment: I am intrigued by your use of a preset array - very interesting results. I'll mark it as an answer unless a better solution comes. May I ask if it is possible to convert the ArrayBuffer into a Number and perform xor? Sort of like how python allows you to change `bytes` to `int` ?

Comment: it might be, but I don't think you'll gain much. Each bit still needs to be XOR'd, and there is no way around this.

Comment: Is it not possible to `xor` 2-4 bytes at a time? Taking advantage of 32-64 bit machines' registers?

Comment: [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) is a logic gate. it takes two inputs and returns a single output

Comment: @EyuelDK yes, a^b is most certainly compiles down to the xor assembly instruction and doing the XOR 4 bytes at a time. it's not doing a xor bit by bit in a loop :) There's a XOR logic gate and 32 of those are used when doing an assembly XOR on 32 bit registers (not really relevant to the question though!).

Comment: Oh I just realized @JMP answer is using arrays of 1s and 0s, not sure why you accepted it :O FWIW, your own answer was probably a loooot faster and memory efficient. You might want to try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics/xor though.